# shell script - why code executing in infinite loop

Tags: shell, unix

Can you please suggest why below code is going into infinite loop -

```
declare -i validationRetry=5

while [ $validationRetry > 0 ]; do

        echo "hello$validationRetry"
        validationRetry=$validationRetry-1
        if [ $validationRetry > 2 ]; then
                validationRetry=0
        fi
        echo "Hello$validationRetry"
done
```

Comment: `> 0` writes to a file named `0`. It's not a comparison.

Comment: Use `-gt` for a comparison.

Comment: Also, run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: Also, `declare -i` is a bashism. To make your code work on all POSIX shells, after fixing everything shellcheck finds, take out the `declare -i validationRetry`, and instead use `validationRetry=$(( validationRetry - 1 ))` or such.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  thanks for shellcheck.com . i wasn't  aware about this . thanks for this!!

Comment: ...if you *were* using bash, by the way, `for ((validationRetry=5; validationRetry > 0; validationRetry--)); do` would be a bit more readable. That said, it's not POSIX compliant, so you can't reliably use that with `#!/bin/sh`.